# jquery with htaccess friendly url help me

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

sorry for my english,
i have a problem with htaccess with jquery.

index.php with this command: "`<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>`" with htacess dont work, result: http://haluze.eu/obrazky/

index.php without this command: "`<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>`" with htacess works perfect

my htacces for testing:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.haluze.eu$
RewriteRule (.*) http://haluze.eu/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^obrazky/(.*) index.php?s=pic$1
```

could you please help me? :)
i am lost...

Comment: If i visit site like this: http://haluze.eu/index.php?s=pic everything works, but look at this: http://haluze.eu/obrazky/. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude files/directories from your rewrite rules.

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(haluze\.eu)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^obrazky/(.*)$ index.php?s=pic$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for very fast ansfer i am really surprised :) but it does not help... same result... no error no warning... just i see only counter and advertisement, whole site dissapear.

Comment: Ok open your page in Firebug and see what URIs result in 404 in `Net tab`

Answer (score 0):

Solution number one (possible)

Try putting a dot into the route of the jquery file

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Solution number Two
Use a jQuery CDN, lower requests to your server

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, it didnt help :( i tried both solutions, still same result... site dissapear